# Alternative to FK for sys.objects reference

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, audit

I'm updating an audit/log table that is populated by trigger when a table is updated. My intention is to use the `sys.objects.object_id` for table name and column name columns in the log table but it's not possible to use a FK reference for the system views. Is there any useful alternative to maintain referential integrity on the table?

Comment: For what purpose? To prevent someone from dropping and recreating the table? What if there is a valid reason to do that? The fact that you logged some information about a table shouldn't lock that table into existence forever.

Comment: Fair point. I've generally worked from the principle that the database should, where practical, make it difficult for users to do stupid things. Inserting or updating a row with incorrect data when that can be prevented would be one of those situations but in this case the table should only be updated by trigger so the data should be correct.

Comment: Are you letting users supply the `object_id` to your log table? (Also tangential but maybe you should consider using the name instead of the id, or both, depending on whether it is more likely for an object to get dropped or renamed.)

Comment: Right, if a table is dropped and re-created then it will get a new `object_id` which would result in existing data being orphaned. But there is a storage penalty to using the table name for logging as opposed to the int `object_id` which is why I was leaning in that direction. The `object_id` is derived in the trigger from the `parent_object_id` of `@@PROCID`.

Comment: Well, even if storing the name is the straw that breaks your storage, you could store the object_id + name combination _once_ in another table, the first time you see each combination. Then your log table could store a surrogate and for the first 2 billion entries you could benefit from *less* storage due to data / columnstore compression. (I'm not trying to design your system, I'm just suggesting that losing information because "it takes too much storage" is not an unsolvable problem.)

Comment: Makes sense - the broader context is the system needs to provide the ability for a user to drill down into the changes for a row so I need to be able to reconstruct that history from the current row in the source table and the matching log entries in the log table.

Comment: It sounds like you're reinventing [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables). :-)

Comment: Does kind of doesn't it - client is currently on 2008r2.

Comment: That kind of client gets no sympathy from me.

Comment: It's all about the context. A great product/system but funding constraints, a large product backlog, much technical debt, and a small pool of knowedgleable talent in a provincial town. Perhaps not sympathy but some compassion?

Comment: Well, maybe, it’s hard for me to understand the full context of every person I interact with here, but I put less and less weight these days in excuses for keeping around unsupported software from more than a decade ago, especially when the reason is budget. Because how much time (& time is money) will you spend supporting this thing without Microsoft’s help, reinventing features that are just available out of the box in newer versions, and what is the cost of just doing without the ones you don’t have time or expertise to reinvent? If you don't have the money, you don't have the money, but...

Comment: The other thing about sitting on 2008R2 forever is that, while you're unlikely to come across any _functional_ bugs that haven't been addressed in service packs long ago, you stop getting _security_ fixes. That risk isn't a tangible line item on your budget, but it's not free. And if you need to open a case with Microsoft (say, for a stack dump, or corruption, or anything else your team can't handle), you are completely out of luck. Either of those scenarios can lead to a cost that is a _lot higher_ than a license.

Comment: Yes fully agree with what you've said. They are in the process of moving to Azure managed sql so I may have been a little disingenuous with my comment re temporal tables. But the requirement for the logging/audit functionality is immediate in order to meet a contractual deadline where the move to a managed db is going to take a little longer and the move to temporal tables is not something I can do unilaterally. It's been really helpful to have your input, ngā mihi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a trigger on the log table that rolls back when the object_id being inserted is not found in sys.objects - since triggers are the typical mechanism we use when a foreign key doesn't make sense or isn't possible (like maintaining integrity across database or instance boundaries).

But do you really want to lose all of the data because one column represents an object that no longer exists, or never existed? (Maybe that's ok; I don't what you're auditing/logging.) What is the likelihood of this happening since the trigger produces the object_id, and the system isn't known for messing up?

I'm not sure I understand the point anyway; while a foreign key to sys.objects would prevent someone from logging information about an object that doesn't exist, the presence of just one row in the logging table would make it impossible to ever drop that object. (Maybe that's ok too, but it doesn't sound wise.)

If the fear is that someday a user reviewing log history will hit a dead end because the object has since been dropped, a trigger that made sure the object existed when the row was inserted isn't going to have saved you from that scenario anyway. You'd need a DDL trigger maybe, on `DROP_TABLE`, so that either the log history associated with that table is purged, or the object_id is moved somewhere else so that you can still track down what that table used to be.